# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() with dating the fossil question

Tags: python, valueerror

I tried to wrote a piece of code when given the percent of carbon is still C 14, which is 35% and to calculate when the fossil formed. I assume it is between half life and twice the half life, therefore the range I offered: However, I received an error msg

```
t=np.arange(5730,5730*2,1)

while t in range(5730,5730*2):
    if 0.5**(t/5700)>0.35:
        t+=1
    else:
        break
        print(t)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-cb11e85c664a> in <module>
      4 t=np.arange(5730,5730*2,1)
      5 
----> 6 while t in range(5730,5730*2):
      7     if 0.5**(t/5700)>0.35:
      8         t+=1

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

x in y doesn't make sense to ask in your scenario

t in range(..) would require t to be a single value but its an element

numpy does some weird stuff and essentially tells you it expects 1 value but you have an array

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop instead of while loop. Also you are printig `t` after braking the loop, so your `t` will never get printed

Use this instead:

```py
t = np.arange(5730,5730*2,1)

for t in range(5730,5730*2,1):
  
  if 0.5**(t/5700)>0.35:
    t+=1
  else:
    print(t)
    break
```